# No Space Left On Device Error

Tags: docker, partition, disk-volume

I have an AWS EC2 instance provisioned with 2 EBS volumes (the root and an extra block volume).

I am hosting several docker applications behind and nginx reverse proxy on this server.  I am getting a

> no space left on device

Error when trying to deploy a new image of my apps.

The root volume was initially provisioned with 8GB and the extra data volume was provisioned with 100GB.

In attempting to fix this problem - I expanded the root volume to 50GB and then extended the file system using [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html) link.

[image]

[image]

Running the df command

```
df -h
```

I only see the original 8GB on the root volume and at capacity (explaining the error).

[image]

When I provisioned instance - I mounted the "data" volume and attached it using [these](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html) instructions.

The data volume is available (I have bind mounts for some of my containers using this directory).

[image]

I have even moved the default docker directory to a directory on the data volume following [these](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-move-the-default-var-lib-docker-to-another-directory-for-docker-on-linux) instructions.

How do I expand the system to leverage the additional 142GB of storage that should be available?

As you can tell system administration is not my strongest area (I am a developer by trade).

Comment: Did you make an Amazon EBS snapshot before you started making changes? Did you run the command `sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1` to extend the `nvme0n1p1` partition to 50GB? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html

Comment: Yes I did that.  I saw the file system change from 8 to 50.  I think the issue is the system partition is still limited to 8.

Comment: You have not expanded your partition. Hopefully this can be to some help: https://blogs.linux.pizza/expanding-the-drive-on-a-live-linux-system